# SQL: single column that shows the average age

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like the following:

| categories | age |
| --- | --- |
| cat_1 | 12 |
| cat_2 | 32 |
| cat_1 | 14 |
| cat_2 | 25 |
| cat_1 | 17 |

What I am trying to do is to have the category names as columns and then the value should be the average of that category. Something similar to the following:

| cat_1 | cat_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 14.33 | 28.5 |

I have tried the following code but it doesn't give me them as columns.

```
select 
    avg(case when category = 'cat_1' then age end) as cat_1
from table
group by category
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
pivot (avg(age) for categories in ('cat_1', 'cat_2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `group by`:

```
select avg(case when category = 'cat_1' then age end) as cat_1,
       avg(case when category = 'cat_2' then age end) as cat_2       
from table;
```